# Need help breaking loop if the user input is an empty line

Tags: java, loops

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class HighestTestAverage {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            int i = 0;
            int scores = 0;
            int number_of = 0;
            int total = 0;
            double average = 0;
            double greatest_average = 0;
            String The_student;
    
            for (i = 1; i != 2; ) {
                
    
                System.out.print("Enter a student's name: ");
    
                String student_name = input.next();
    
                if(student_name.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(Breaking loop");
                }
    }
```

Whenever I try to put a blank line where it asks "Enter a student's name", it doesn't print Breaking loop. I have tried many things but none of them works. Some of the variables I have are for the later part of the code so they are unnecessary at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

if instead of `input.next()` you use `input.nextLine()`, should go
and you want a infinity loop?
because if not it would be better to use `while(true){}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` keyword, it will break out of for / white loops:

```
for (i = 1; i != 2; ) { 
  System.out.print("Enter a student's name: ");
  String student_name = input.next();
  if (student_name.isEmpty()) {
    break;
  }
}
```

For better understanding read about [`break` and `continue`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The method isEmpty only becomes true if student_name is null. A blank white space is not null, but a whitespace character. To solve this, use if(stuent_name.equals(" ")) {...

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Scanner`, there are two ways to do it:

**Option-1:** Use `Scanner#nextLine`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String studentName = "";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a student's name: ");
            studentName = input.nextLine();
        } while (!studentName.isBlank());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a student's name: Hello
Enter a student's name: World
Enter a student's name:
```

**Option-2:** Use `Scanner#next` with delimiter as `[\r\n]` or `\R`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter("[\r\n]"); // input.useDelimiter("\\R");
        String studentName = "";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a student's name: ");
            studentName = input.next();
        } while (!studentName.isBlank());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a student's name: Hello
Enter a student's name: World
Enter a student's name:
```